# How I can hide original directory of linked folders in terminal while i use ”ls -la”

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

[image: Example]

I often use `ls -la` command for view hidden files in terminal.
But I'm uncomfortable with the fact that it shows and links to directories of linked folders.
Can I hide this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-L` option may be what you are looking for, although this also changes what metadata is shown. Without `-L`, you get permissions, size, etc for the symlink. With `-L`, the symlink's name alone is shown, but with the permissions, size, etc of the target.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -la /usr/bin/ | awk 'BEGIN{FS="->"}{print $1}'
```

then you can alias it , so don't have to type all of that every time

Comment: Unless a file name actually contains the string `->`; don't parse `ls`.